# Privileged Instruction when calling "Cancel" on a client dataset

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

This is a really interesting error indeed :)
I have a child form inheriting from a base form.
The base form provides all sorts of virtual;abstract; services for use by children.
This form uses all of them :) one of the services is a Save/Cancel system, which is coded in this way in the base form:

```
procedure TBaseRecordFrm.ConfirmSave(AVal: Boolean);
begin
  if AVal then
    PerformSave
  else
    PerformCancel;
  Close;
end;
```

The inherited form does something quite simple: in the Ok and Cancel button calls ConfirmSave with the appropriate parameter(True/False).
The code for the two methods is pretty straight-forward:

```
procedure TActionFrm.PerformCancel;
begin
  if DMMain.CDSActionItems.State in dsEditModes then
    DMMain.CDSActionItems.Cancel;
end;

procedure TActionFrm.PerformSave;
begin
  if DMMain.CDSActionItems.State in dsEditModes then
    DMMain.CDSActionItems.Post;
end;
```

When pressing "Cancel", I get a "Privileged Instruction" exception.
I am not doing anything spectacular as far as I can see.
Anybody can shed some light, please? :)

Thank you!

Andrea

Comment: That happens when you execute code that is meant to be run in ring 0, code that talks to hardware etc. Can happen with codegen compiler bug.

Comment: Adding "MidasLib" to the project did the trick. Please note that I failed to mention I am building with packages(due to DevExpress trial) and this seems to not go down well with the Delphi IDE.